# Dynamically selecting data sources in Spring Hibernate - approaches

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

Is there a simple way to Choose the datasource by reading from UI or a properties file using Spring and Hibernate, if for eg. the Datasources are X and Y. ?

One approach would be to have dual configuration of sessionfactory, datasource and transaction manager. Then, based on the selection of datasource, the DAO is injected with the appropriate sessionfactory. Is there a better option?

My scenario is that I should be able to switch between two databases on the fly as and when client requires a change in DB for the same application.

Is it a good approach to have DAO with DB compatible methods for eg. a method to retrieve data from DB X and another method to retrieve Data from DB Y as data retrieval varies from one DB to another and calling the methods dynamically at run-time.

or

Is it a better approach to have different versions of same application altogether for X and Y databases for the sake of Database compatibility with java ? If this is the right approach I would like to understand why ?

Comment: Take a Look at Spring Profile. It should help.

Comment: Thanks for helping me with an option, though I wouldn't prefer Spring profile as I think it wouldn't exactly match my scenario for a simple solution.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Spring profiles you can also consider Spring's [AbstractRoutingDataSource](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.0.8/api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/lookup/AbstractRoutingDataSource.html)

> The general idea is that a routing DataSource acts as an intermediary
>   - while the ‘real’ DataSource can be determined dynamically at runtime based upon a lookup key.

You can find more info in this [blog](https://spring.io/blog/2007/01/23/dynamic-datasource-routing/) and a somewhat newer [post](http://howtodoinjava.com/2013/12/28/spring-3-2-5-abstractroutingdatasource-example/), giving an exemplary use with hibernate.

The [AbstractRoutingDataSource](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.0.8/api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/lookup/AbstractRoutingDataSource.html) is easy to use and will support your scenario where you need to switch the DBs on the fly based on some parameter. The later post gives you an example where the switch is made on the fly based on the user selected locale

Comment: Thanks. I think AbstractRoutingDataSource is easy, when there are datasources of same type for eg. Oracle. But If I need to have another  DB connection eg SQLSERVER, then I will have to make changes in my DAO layer if Im setting some parameters to stored procedures etc. and this may vary from one DB to another.

Answer (score 1):

I have used option one with success: property file, people can change it even by themselves. If you manage to make two implementations of a Dao interface that behave in the same way then go for it, I don't see any reason to do two different applications.

Define `config.dao.id` with value `daoOracle` or `daoMySql`

```
<bean id='daoOracle' abstract='true' class='...'/>
<bean id='daoMySql' abstract='true' class='...'/>

<bean id='dao' parent='${config.dao.id}'/>

<bean id='myService' class='...'>
   <property name='dao' ref='dao'>
</bean>
```

Comment: Property file look up for connection can be done, but I did not find a way for the application to automatically implement the correct version of DAO. For eg. if my property file is configured with Oracle connection, how can I make sure that only the Oracle compatible DAO is executed ? any solution ?

Comment: "automatically implement" or "select" ? to "select" you need an other property that identifies the implementation, then create an alias and reference it from services.

Comment: if I have 2 DAO's for 2 different databases then how do my application know to select one of them by reading the property file. please give more details as how to reference it from service using alias. I think I'm coming close to the solution..